# DataSet vs. DataTable Array objects

Tags: asp.net

DataSet is said to be a collection of one or more DataTable objects. 
Is it possible to use an array of DataTable objects?
If yes, then why use a DataSet? Are there any advantages?
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

A [**`DataSet`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has some extra properties rather than a simple `Array` of `DataTable`. For instance, it is serializable.

You should always stick to existing .NET classes rather than inventing new ones.

Comment: Serializable meaning?

Comment: It means converting data in any form to objects.

Answer (score 0):

In an object oriented language, people preferred to use an object rather than an array. It's more intuitive for anyone reading your code if you use DataSet.Datatable(TheTableName). You can briefly describe what's inside of that table with the table name. By contrast, creating an array of tables is not a good idea. Take a look at this code: DataTableArray(0) = MyDataTable . The next time if you tried to find MyDataTable,  it's not possible for anyone who's reading your code to remember that MyDataTable is restored in DataTableArray with an index of 0. This concept is also applied in the concept of LINQ.

Please take a look at this page. MSDN helps.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/bb397897.aspx